# Pandas Week of Year from July 1

Tags: python, pandas

So I have pandas dataframe with a 'date' column.  Our calendar is based off of July 1st being the first day.  I know I can do df['date'].dt.week, but that gives me the week from Jan 1.  Is there a way to take my df and make a new column 'week' where 'week' is 0 for the first days in July until Sunday and then 1... etc.?  Basically the same way that dt.week works... just shifted to Jul 1.  I know that resample allows me to shift this way, I just can't seem to figure out how to get it all correct as a column.

Thanks

Update:  Currently doing this... not exactly working.

```
def get_academic_year(x):
    if (x.month < 7):
        year = x.year - 1
    else:
        year = x.year
    return year

def get_week(x):
    return ((x['date'].week - 
    pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime(x['academic_year'], 7, 1)).week) % 52)

df_x['academic_year'] = df_x['date'].apply(lambda x: get_academic_year(x))
df_x['week'] = df_x.apply(lambda x: get_week(x), axis=1)
```

My Dataset:

```
'{"date":{"0":1414368000000,"1":1414454400000,"2":1414540800000,"3":1414627200000,"4":1414713600000,"5":1414800000000,"6":1414886400000,"7":1425254400000,"8":1425340800000,"9":1425427200000,"10":1425513600000,"11":1425600000000,"12":1425686400000,"13":1425772800000,"14":1433116800000,"15":1433203200000,"16":1433289600000,"17":1433376000000,"18":1433462400000,"19":1433548800000,"20":1433635200000,"21":1444262400000,"22":1444348800000,"23":1444608000000,"24":1444694400000,"25":1444780800000,"26":1444867200000,"27":1444953600000,"28":1445040000000,"29":1445126400000,"30":1452643200000,"31":1452729600000,"32":1452816000000,"33":1452902400000,"34":1452988800000,"35":1460505600000,"36":1460937600000,"37":1461024000000,"38":1461110400000,"39":1461196800000,"40":1461283200000,"41":1461369600000,"42":1461456000000,"43":1465776000000,"44":1465862400000,"45":1465948800000,"46":1466035200000,"47":1466121600000,"48":1470873600000,"49":1470960000000,"50":1471219200000,"51":1471305600000,"52":1471392000000,"53":1486598400000,"54":1489968000000,"55":1490054400000,"56":1490140800000,"57":1490227200000,"58":1490313600000,"59":1492387200000,"60":1492473600000,"61":1492560000000,"62":1492646400000,"63":1492732800000,"64":1494201600000,"65":1494288000000,"66":1494374400000,"67":1494460800000,"68":1494547200000,"69":1502668800000,"70":1502755200000,"71":1502841600000,"72":1502928000000,"73":1503014400000,"74":1503100800000,"75":1503187200000,"76":1505174400000,"77":1505433600000,"78":1507507200000,"79":1507593600000,"80":1507680000000,"81":1507766400000,"82":1507852800000,"83":1507939200000,"84":1508025600000,"85":1508976000000,"86":1509062400000,"87":1509148800000,"88":1509235200000,"89":1509321600000,"90":1509408000000,"91":1512086400000,"92":1524268800000,"93":1524355200000,"94":1529884800000,"95":1529971200000,"96":1530057600000,"97":1530144000000,"98":1530230400000}}'
```

Update #2:

```
def get_academic_year(x):
    if (x.month < 7):
        year = x.year - 1
    else:
        year = x.year
    return year

def get_week(x):
    return int(((x['date'] - pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime(x['academic_year'], 7, 1)))).days / 7) + 1

rng = pd.date_range('7/1/2015', periods=365*3, freq='D')
df_x = pd.DataFrame()
df_x['date'] = rng
df_x['academic_year'] = df_x['date'].apply(lambda x: get_academic_year(x))
df_x['week'] = df_x.apply(lambda x: get_week(x), axis=1)
df_x
```

Comment: `(dt.week - july_01.week) % 52` where `july_01` is a datetime object for your reference day.  Depending on your handling at end-of-calendar-year, you may need to adjust a day somewhere, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Would I need a different July_01 for each year?....

Comment: Yes; extracting the current year should be easy enough.

Comment: @EFaden, did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask further questions. Or, if you solved the problem yourself, please post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2017-07-05', '2017-07-21', '2017-07-22',
                         '2017-08-01','2017-08-15', '2017-08-30']})

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
df['Week'] = df['A'].dt.week - pd.to_datetime('2017-07-01').week

#            A  Week
# 0 2017-07-05     1
# 1 2017-07-21     3
# 2 2017-07-22     3
# 3 2017-08-01     5
# 4 2017-08-15     7
# 5 2017-08-30     9
```

Comment: I want the week of the year... e.g. 0 to 52, but instead of the .week starting Jan 1, I want to start Jul 7.... although this may work... I

Comment: Added the dateset I'm testing with

Comment: @EFaden, and how to do you convert it to `datetime` ?

Comment: See update #2.... I think I got it mostly worked... I tweaked it a bit to make 7/1 - 7/7 week 1, etc....

Comment: I see, if you get it working, feel free to post a solution yourself.